# Displaying graph labels, outcome not expected

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following two graphs:

```
graph1 = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {3 -> 3, 2 -> 2, 1 -> 1}]

graph2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> {3 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 2}]
```

and the list containing both

```
graphlist = {graph1, graph2}
```

The code:

```
testgraphs = 
 SetProperty[#, 
    VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{Style[v, Blue]}, {Above}]}] & /@ 
  graphlist
```

produces two V-shaped graphs, for which the labels (displayed in Blue) are the same for each vertex (across the graphs).

I expect these to be different as the VertexLabels for graph1 and graph2 are different.

Is there an issue with the code?

Comment: `v_ :> Placed[{Style[v, Blue]}, {Above}]` labels every node with its _name_ (not with its `VertexLabels` in the input graph.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
testgraphs = SetProperty[#,  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
    Placed[{Style[PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexLabels], Blue]}, {Above}]}] & /@ 
   graphlist;

testgraphs
```

[image]

Comment: Very confusing: I tried both Style[PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexLabels], Blue] and removing the assignment testgraphs =  separately. Neither worked separately. The combination works. Is it because the language is so buggy? Or am I missing something regarding the constructs?

Comment: @Mike, can you post the code(s) that did not /did work?

Comment: I just checked and it actually works for assignments. Only fails for {Style[v, Blue]}